# google places autocomplete vs geocode + angular

Tags: angular, google-maps

I try to use google maps in angular app. I am using ngui map(just a library for google maps)
I can use autocomplete for places - no problem.
However, when I use geocoding (to check manually entered address and get its coordinates) I always get an error saying

> Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this
>   API.
>   Why is it happening?

Probably piece of code will help
here how it looks like (I even use debounce time to send requests not so often) but still no luck

```
this.addressSearch$ = this.searchTerms
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap( 
        (data: string) => this.geocoder.geocode({address: data})
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    )
```

Comment: You are likely not including an API key in your geocoding request. An API key is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

**Developer Api key has daily quota** for Api calls. If the calls exceed daily limit, such warnings would be shown.

Comment: Ok, then why does it work okay for autocomplete but fails for geocode